# Django Sitemaps : Get only pages of the current website

Tags: django, django-models, django-sites, django-sitemaps

I would like to create a Site specific Sitemap using Django Sitemaps.

My idea was to do something like this :

```
def items(self):
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current(self.request)
    return current_site.pages.filter(draft=False)
```

But I have two issues :

1. `self.request` is not defined, is there a way to get the real `current_site` inside the Sitemap ?
2. The items URL is not right, it should starts with the right `current_site`

I guess, I have to pass directly the right queryset to my Sitemap, but how can I do that ?

Thanks,

Rémy

Comment: Why you are passing `self.request` to `get_current` method? simply call `Site.objects.get_current()` this will give you current site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the site specific queryset by this way.

```
def items(self):   
  return YourModel.objects.by_site()
```

`by_site` is `YourModel`'s manager function,

```
def by_site(self, site=None, **kwargs):
    """Get all pages for this site"""
    if not site:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()

    site = site.id

    return self.filter(site__id__exact = site, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes but in this case Site.objects.get_current() will return the settings.SITE_ID one instead of the RequestSite

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like the `sites` framework is being used the wrong way

The `sites` framework isn't intended to dynamically switch sites based on the request. It is for use with multiple separate deployments running from the same database.

**Issue 1:**

To fix your `items()` function, `SITE_ID` needs to be set in `settings.py` Which lets `Site.objects.get_current()` work anywhere, without needing a `request` object.

**Issue 2:**

Domain names should **not** be included in the urls. The sitemap is requested from a domain, so everything is known to be on that domain.

This goes for all urls within django.

To fix it, make sure the `get_absolute_url()` method on your model is returning a string starting with `"/"`. Not anything relating to a domain name.

The url for an item is generated with `get_absolute_url()` or by calling [`Sitemap.location()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.location) with the item. The documentation for `location()` examples about what form the url should be in.

For more information check out this [bug ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17802), about the same issue.

Comment: Actually, I am using `Site` the way I need it for my SaaS. But I think using the `SITE_ID` is just a simple way of using this contrib app.

Comment: `SITE_ID` is **the** way to use `contrib.sites`. The alternative `RequestSite`/`get_current_site(request)` is just a convenience fallback for when not using `contrib.sites`.

If you want to use it this way you'll have to override some methods in the the `Sitemap` class, which may change and break in the future.

Comment: Ok so I can also fork the Sitemap app and create one which will worK.